# How are PSKs agreed upon by the TLS server and client?

Tags: tls, psk

I've read that pre-shared keys (PSKs) are symmetric keys shared in advance among communicating parties but have found no explanation as to how the TLS client and server agree upon the value of the PSK.  How is this done?

Comment: You don't *agree* on a pre-shared key. It's shared before.

Thus, if your TLS client connects to a server it doesn't know, it can't have any common info with the server. 

I.e. PSKs don't apply to TLS.

Comment: Marcus Müller 1 Thank you for your response. You said: "You don't agree on a pre-shared key. It's shared before." Yes, that is my question... how is it shared before? For example, is the PSK loaded in a secure environment during manufacturing?

Comment: Thank you Harry Johnston for your reply. Unfortunately, the answer to the post does not seem to explain how the PSK is loaded (pre-shared) into the server and the client.

Comment: Use a side channel.  Any side channel works, but the most common is either copying files over, or an administrator types the key in. **It doesn't matter how**; there are as many ways to do it as there are ways to share _any_ type of information.  It just matters that, somehow, somewhere, some administrator got involved and put the key on both systems, before the systems were set up to talk to each other.

Comment: @MarcusMüller TLS-PSK is definitely a crypto protocol, with RFC standards (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4279) and even a wiki page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TLS-PSK)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### How is the PSK shared?

A pre-shared key is, by definition, *pre*-shared. The term for this is that it is distributed *out-of-band*. In other words, the protocol does not prescribe a mechanism for sharing the key. It could be done using a logically-separate key agreement protocol, or by being generated from a shared secret hardcoded in both devices, or over a wireless NFC connection, or even by being directly typed in through a keyboard by a human. The point is that the PSK is shared exclusively out-of-band.

The definition of out-of-band, according to Wikipedia:

> [...] an agreement or understanding between the communicating parties that is not included in any message sent over the channel but which is relevant for the interpretation of such messages.

### How is the PSK used?

There are three main suites in TLS-PSK. The first, PSK, uses this shared-secret directly to derive all symmetric key material for the protocol. The latter two, RSA_PSK and DHE_PSK, only use the PSK in place of a standard digital certificate. TLS-PSK is used to refer to any of these three suites:

- [**PSK**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4279#section-2) directly uses the pre-shared secret to derive the premaster secret, which itself is used to generate all other symmetric keys used by the protocol. If the PSK is stolen, confidentiality and authenticity are completely lost. That is, an attacker can passively decrypt stored sessions.
- [**RSA_PSK**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4279#section-4) uses the pre-shared secret only for authentication in place of a standard certificate. The actual premaster secret is exchanged using RSA. If an attacker manages to steal the PSK, they will be able to perform a MITM attack, but a passive attacker will be thwarted.
- [**DHE_PSK**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4279#section-3) is like RSA_PSK, but using Diffie-Hellman (DH) rather than RSA. DH provides forward secrecy. It is stronger than RSA in that the private key is ephemeral and never stored. There is less risk that the private key will be stolen, to allow passive decryption of recorded sessions.

Answer (score 0):

To verify that the server is the correct one and not some man in the middle TLS the server authenticates itself against the server.

Usually this is done with certificates: here the server sends a certificate, proves (by signing some challenge) that it owns the private key for this certificate and the client checks if the certificate is valid for the server. This validation requires the client to have some **pre-existing local trust anchor**, i.e. either the certificate itself is trusted (pinning) or the CA which (directly or indirectly) issued the CA is trusted.

With DHE-PSK or RSA-PSK as defined in [RFC 4279 section 3 and 4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4279#section-3) this is similar: the client has some **pre-existing local trust anchor**, which is not a CA but in this case the expected PSK. The server again proves knowledge of the PSK to the client similar to how it proved ownership of the private key of the certificate before. With PSK key exchange as defined in [RFC 4279 section 2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4279#section-2) no explicit authentication is done at all but the PSK is used directly to derive the keys for encryption. But without knowledge of the key the data cannot be decrypted which implicitly authenticates the peer.

How the PSK is put on the client **before the TLS handshake** (and thus before the authentication) is not defined similar to how it is not defined how the local trust store is setup with CA before the authentication. Of course, it has to be done in some secure way, for example when setting up the device at the vendor before it gets shipped to the customer.

Comment: Reading the RFC at least, the PSK (as opposed to PSK_DHE or PSK_RSA) algorithm derives the premaster secret _directly_ from the PSK, so it doesn't seem like it's used only for authentication.

Comment: @forest: as far as I understand [RFC 4279](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4279) it is used for authentication only, the key itself is exchanged using Diffie-Hellman or other key exchange methods.

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4279#section-2: _The premaster secret is formed as follows: if the PSK is N octets long, concatenate a uint16 with the value N, N zero octets, a second uint16 with the value N, and the PSK itself._

Comment: @forest: I see - in case of PSK key exchange the encryption keys are derived from the PSK, in case of DHE_PSK the PSK is only used for authenticate the peer.